# d3.js Force-Directed Graph with rect collide

Tags: d3.js

I trying crete force-Directed Graph. My nodes is rect, and they overlap each other. There are examples in which overlapping is removed, but there are no links. Help me please modify the graph to avoid overlapping.

What the distributor offers can be applied to circles:

```
.force('collision', d3.forceCollide().radius(function(d) {
   return d.radius
}))
```

My case:
https://jsfiddle.net/MoOgur/7mc1jm77/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=7mc1jm77

Links must participate in the simulation, but should not be drawn.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you add `.strength(-80))` in line 46 in your example behind the `.force("charge", d3.forceManyBody()` it gets better.

You can change the "80" to something else. As you go closer to "0" the graph lookes more focused.

It depends how much space you have on your page. If there is **not** enough then this solution **won't** work.